# Large data object - am I worrying too much

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I work with EF for the first time so I don't know is situation like this normal or I have serious performance issues.
I have following situation:

Bellow are the classes that I have. Item is the main object here. So when I pull a list of Items from database I get for example 1000 items. And now each of this item has all properties filed with data. City contains Country, Country contains list of cities, User has list of created items, each item all data again, city, city has country, country list of cities etc etc...
Maybe I am worrying too much and I don't know should this object's contain all those data and does this make performance issues, or I am doing something wrong here?

```
public abstract class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOnDate { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int? MediaId { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ItemInBoard> ItemsInBoard { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }        
    }
public class City
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    }
public class Country
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
    }
public class User
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BirthDay { get; set; }
        public string AboutMe { get; set; }
        public int? MediaId { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Board> Boards { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is up to you.  This is a concept called lazy loading.  You can enable or disable lazy loading with this code:

```
  context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
  context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

When enabling this option none of the dependent entities will be loaded.  To enforce dependent entities to load you can use the Include lambada expression like this:

```
   var test = context.Tests.Include("SomeOtherDependentEntity");
```

Hope I got you and this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that what you have is fine for general business logic.

When I have to do a lot of time sensitive processing in a read-only fashion I use SQL commands like this to get exactly and only exactly what I want.

```
public class myQueryClass
{
public string Property1 { get; set; }
public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

var context = new MyDbContext();
context.Database.SqlQuery<myQueryClass>("SELECT Property1 = acolumn, Property2 = acolumn2 FROM myTable WHERE something = somestate");
```